# Infinite field extensions and linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have some issues proving this statement, which is an exercise in Jacobson's *Lectures in Abstract Algebra (vol. 3)*:

- Let $P$ be an arbitrary extension field of $\Phi$. Show that, if $\alpha \in P$ satisfies $\alpha_R \circ f = f \circ \alpha_R$ for all $f \in hom_{\Phi} \left ( P, P \right )$ then $\alpha \in \Phi$, where: $\alpha_R$ is the defined as $\alpha_R:P \rightarrow P, \alpha_R\left ( p  \right ) = p.\alpha$, and $hom_{\Phi}\left ( P, P \right )$ represents the set of $\Phi$-linear transformations from $P$ to $P$.

In other words, that the only elements of $P$ that can be "taken out" from every linear transformation are the elements of $\Phi$. Now, as a consequence of a theorem given in the aforementioned book ("Jacobson-Bourbaki theorem"), the statement is true for finite extensions. However, i don't seem to be able to deduce the general case from the finite one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $\phi$ is a linear transformation than $\phi(1)$ is in P. So $\phi(p)=p\phi(1)$ for every $p\in P$. Don't know if this helps, i can't see the extenction here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $\alpha\in P\setminus\Phi$, that is, $\alpha$ is linearly independent from $1$ in the $\Phi$-vector space $P$.

Then (e.g. by extending $(1,\alpha)$ to a basis) we can define a $\Phi$-linear map $f:P\to P$ that satisfies $f(1)=1,\ f(\alpha)=0$.
This will violate the condition, as
$$\alpha_R(f(1))=\alpha\ \ne\ 0=f(\alpha_R(1))\,.$$

Comment: ahhh i am such an idiot. I was stuck trying to deduce this from complex results when it was so simple. Thank you